# How to get ECDSA Public Key from x509 pem file

Tags: c#, key, public, public-key, ecdsa

I want to get the public key from x509 pem file, I tried to use this library `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;` but couldn't be able to figure it out how to get the Publci key as pem file.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace ScottBrady.Pem.NetCore
{
    public class Program
    {
        private const string CertPem = @"MIID9jCCA5ugAwIBAgITbwAAeCy9aKcLA99HrAABAAB4LDAKBggqhkjOPQQDAjBj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";
        private const string EccPem = @"MHQCAQEEIDyLDaWIn/1/g3PGLrwupV4nTiiLKM59UEqUch1vDfhpoAcGBSuBBAAKoUQDQgAEYYMMoOaFYAhMO/steotfZyavr6p11SSlwsK9azmsLY7b1b+FLhqMArhB2dqHKboxqKNfvkKDePhpqjui5hcn0Q==
";
        
        public static void Main()
        {
            // parsing a cert from a PEM file. PEM labels have been stripped
            var cert = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(CertPem));
            Console.WriteLine($"Certificate loaded with subject '{cert.Subject}' and a key type of '{cert.PublicKey.Oid.FriendlyName}'");
            var keey = cert.GetECDsaPublicKey();
            Console.WriteLine(keey);
            // parsing an ECC key from a PEM file. PEM labels have been stripped
            var key = ECDsa.Create();
            key.ImportECPrivateKey(Convert.FromBase64String(EccPem), out _);
            Console.WriteLine($"Key loaded with key size of '{key.KeySize}'");

            var certWithPrivateKey = cert.CopyWithPrivateKey(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You get the DER encoded X.509/SPKI key with `byte[] der = keey.ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo()` (as of .NET Core 3.0) and the PEM encoded one with `PemEncoding.Write("PUBLIC KEY", der)` (as of .NET 5). In .NET 7 Preview there is even `ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfoPem()`.

Comment: @Topaco Many thanks for reply, I am going to test. but what doest it mean `PemEncoding.Write("PUBLIC KEY", der)' is it the same of 'Console.writeLine' ?

Comment: I am using .NET 5 and I tried `byte[] der = keey.ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo();
            Console.Write("PUBLIC KEY:", der);` but didn't work when I print it in console it gives me `key` only!

Comment: [`PemEncoding.Write()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.pemencoding.write?view=net-6.0#system-security-cryptography-pemencoding-write(system-readonlyspan((system-char))-system-readonlyspan((system-byte)))) simply returns the PEM encoded key (as `char[]`), i.e. try `Console.WriteLine(PemEncoding.Write("PUBLIC KEY", der))`.

Comment: @Topaco but `PemEncoding` doesn't work ! `the name doesn't exist` !

Comment: Check the link above, the `PemEncoding` class exists as of .NET 5 (or s. https://dotnetfiddle.net/wZ4bCh).

Comment: @Topaco , thanks,  it's strange, in your example it works! but in my VS not!

Comment: @Topaco yes it works with `var der = keey.ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo();` many thanks

Comment: @Topaco is there any replacement for NET 4.7.2? :)

Comment: The support of import/export of PEM keys is poor for .NET Framework. Here the most comfortable option is BouncyCastle.